# How to outline the selected row with transparent selection color in WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, styling

Something that looks like this:

[image]

I don't want to change the background or foreground color on selection, only outline the selected row.

Is this possible in WPF? I only see Winforms on SO.

Ok so I added it to my existing resources, so now my XAML code's resources is like this:

```
  <Window.Resources>
        <local:NullImageConverter x:Key="nullImageConverter"/>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#1e90ff"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnAlarmStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#000000"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="RowStyleWithAlternation" TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#141414"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1e1e1e"/>
                </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#1e90ff" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Style.Triggers>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value=" "/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Symbol"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="11"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageColor}" />
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="12"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageColor}" />
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="13"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeDailyBackColor}" />
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeDailyForeColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="14"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeHourlyBackColor}" />
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeHourlyForeColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Min %"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeMinutelyForeColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Net BTC/m"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=LastMinuteVolumeColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                </Trigger>

            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="#006400" CornerRadius="0" Padding="0">
                            <Grid x:Name="PART_Track">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="#640000" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Coins}" IsLiveSortingRequested="True" x:Key="MyKey" />

    </Window.Resources>
```

Final result looks like this:
[image]

So it still uses the background color as set by the alternating colors, and the separator style columns still show up, not sure if there is a way to fix those.

Comment: You would have to override the default styles of `DataGridRow` and `DataGridCell`. You can find all default styles and templates on [Microsoft Docs: Control Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). Select `DataGrid`, copy&paste the styles and modify it.

Answer (score 1):

You have modify `DataGridRow` style. Add trigger when `IsSelected` is true and set `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then modify `DataGridCell` style. Add trigger when `IsSelected` is true and set `Background` and `BorderBrush` to `Null`. Also set `Foreground` color otherwise `Foreground` will be changed when you select a row.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Ok I tried this, it almost worked, but some stuff still doesn't seem to work. I will update OP to show the details.

Comment: I am not sure why, but if I set a color like Red to Background for selected, it works, but x:Null, it doesn't override the existing background color.

Comment: Also can I keep the FG color as is? Because I have many colors, I cant use a fixed color for all.

Comment: @JoanVenge Use the `Transparent` brush instead.

Comment: @BionicCode: I tried that but it didn't work, I will try to find out why. Because some cells have different backgrounds, but not sure why transparent doesnt take effect. I see pure white BG color.

Comment: @JoanVenge The best way is to override the default template. Just don't add any logic to it, only the template layout. There are currently visual states defined which may interfere with your triggers. By overriding the template you are able to remove/modify them. This is generally the recommended approach as simply adding triggers does not always have the desired effect.

Comment: @BionicCode: I think you are right but I think I am on the right path. If I set the Background of the selection to anything, it does set it correctly so that must be working but only Transparent turns it into White. So not sure why it doesn't work. Also if I dont override the background for the selection, then it's using the Alternating Index Background color. Not sure why that is.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a style for DataGridRow. something like this. you can add this style to App.xaml or resource in the window on anywhere you want.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
             <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Comment: You would also have to override the `DataGridCell` style to remove the cell highlighting.

Comment: Yes when I try it, I still have cell highlighting.